# How to reset counter each section with secnumdepth set to 0

Tags: koma-script, counters, scrartcl

I am writing a document using the KOMA-class scrartcl. I enabled `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` at the beginning because I intend to use some other kind of numbering which I write into the section header itself.

Unfortunately, this influences the resetting of counters, as the section counter does not get "activated" (for the lack of a better term) anymore.

Is this even possible to do, i.e. keeping the aforementioned option but still resetting counters with each section?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the problematic option %%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{thatimportantc}[section]
\newcounter{randomcounter}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
    \stepcounter{thatimportantc}\arabic{thatimportantc}~|~%
    \stepcounter{randomcounter}\arabic{randomcounter}
}

\begin{document}
    
\section{The first section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{The second section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

The option to count up section numbers will now be changed via: \verb+\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}+ \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

The counter \verb+thatimportantc+ will now be reset with each section. From hereon forth, you will observe that the counters are not equal anymore.

\section{Third section}

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{4th section}

\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You defined `thatimportantc` to reset every time `section` is incremented, and `randomcounter` not to reset.  So yes, when section is incremented one is reset and the other not, and section is incremented only if `secnumdepth` is greater than 0. Are you sure you don't simply want to change the appearance of the section? In that case is better to still count section, and use `\thesection` to change what is printed (or one of the zillions section-styling packages ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can step the counter for `section`, but suppress its output:

```latex
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the problematic option %%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{thatimportantc}[section]
\newcounter{randomcounter}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
    \stepcounter{thatimportantc}\arabic{thatimportantc}~|~%
    \stepcounter{randomcounter}\arabic{randomcounter}
}

\begin{document}

\section{The first section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{The second section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are not equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{Third section}

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{4th section}

\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will need actions also on the headers, if you use them.

Alternative way: patch `\section` so it steps the relevant counter.

```latex
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the problematic option %%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\preto\section{\stepcounter{section}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcounter{thatimportantc}[section]
\newcounter{randomcounter}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
    \stepcounter{thatimportantc}\arabic{thatimportantc}~|~%
    \stepcounter{randomcounter}\arabic{randomcounter}
}

\begin{document}

\section{The first section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{The second section}

In this section, you will observe that the counters are not equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{Third section}

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{4th section}

\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "alternative" way with the patch is quite easy to grasp and I will use it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Today a new prerelease of KOMA-Script version 3.31 was published. It can be installed from the [KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801). With this version

```latex
\documentclass[
%paper=a4,% default
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}[2020/06/02]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the problematic option %%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{thatimportantc}[section]
\newcounter{randomcounter}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
  \stepcounter{thatimportantc}\arabic{thatimportantc}~|~%
  \stepcounter{randomcounter}\arabic{randomcounter}
}

\begin{document}
\KOMAScriptVersion% show the KOMA-Script version used for the example
\tableofcontents
\section{The first section}
In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{The second section}
In this section, you will observe that the counters are not equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{Third section}
\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{4th section}
\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

If you only want to suppress the section number in document, page header and TOC, you can use:

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\sectionnumdepth}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}% supress section number in document body
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}% supress section number in page header
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}% supress section number in ToC
```

This works with really old versions too. Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
%paper=a4,% default
DIV=15,
parskip=half
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the problematic option %%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\sectionnumdepth}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}% supress section number in document body
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}% supress section number in page header
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}% supress section number in ToC
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{thatimportantc}[section]
\newcounter{randomcounter}

\newcommand{\callingcounters}{%
  \stepcounter{thatimportantc}\arabic{thatimportantc}~|~%
  \stepcounter{randomcounter}\arabic{randomcounter}
}

\begin{document}
\KOMAScriptVersion% show the KOMA-Script version used for the example
\tableofcontents
\section{The first section}
In this section, you will observe that the counters are equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{The second section}
In this section, you will observe that the counters are not equal (as expected).

\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{Third section}
\callingcounters\\
\callingcounters

\section{4th section}
\callingcounters

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hahaha wow, I think this might actually be a crazy conincidence :) Highly doubt that this question warrants a patch, I suppose this was in the making for quite some time. There are quite a few related questions... but as far as I can tell at first glance, they all relate to the starred versions of the structuring-commands. As I am on Arch Linux and am using its official TL packages, the update *might* take months to reach my installation.